# What would you call death by magnetar?

Tags: magnetar

The magnetic field of a magnetar is so strong that it would stretch people's atoms apart. This, would obviously, result in death. But how spaghettification refers to death by extreme tides, and for the most part, refers to death by black hole, what field-specific term would best refer to death by extreme magnetic fields, eg. from a magnetar?

[image: Magnetar]

Comment: Isn't this better suited for meta stackexchange? I believe there is some astronomy jokes section there and people can try and come up with creative answers such as teslascind there...

Comment: "Magnetaaarrgh!"

Comment: ESE can be a tough room sometimes. I've had some degree of success but you have to be fairly careful how the question is asked, demonstrate prior research, and stick to real or at least nearly-real words. [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/387446/217285), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370655/217285), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/547154/217285), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/492223/217285), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/490515/217285), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/466998/217285).

Comment: I think this question would be better if you added one more sentence asking for a potentially scientific word for what happens to inanimate matter, like a dust particle. You could also ask that as a separate question and that might be better... or not.

Comment: Mag-neato.  X-men joke.  Which I wouldn't have explained if there wasn't a minimum character requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has ever needed such a word, and it doesn't exist.

"Spaghetification" is, of course, a joke word, but each time you make a new joke based off an old one, the less funny it becomes.

If you just want a (poor) joke:  Teslascind

---

In order to capture [@pela's ephemeral comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/what-would-you-call-death-by-magnetar#comment77510_39011) in a more durable post:

> Magnetaaarrgh!

---

Comment: I like it 

Comment: I didn't know that `Spaghetification` was a joke though, I though it was the original term

Comment: It is a science term: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification

Comment: @WDUK Maybe it was a joke that caught on so well it ended up a scientific term